# Facebook REST API Like/UnLike for any post not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am developing Facebook Client Application for the device and I'am using REST APIs.
Till yesterday, Like/UnLike feature was working well for all posts.
Today i test again, and found its not working.
its throwing
"error_code": 100,
"error_msg": "Invalid parameter",

I checked facebook developers website and found
"We are in the process of deprecating the REST API. If you are building a new Facebook application, please use the Graph API. While there is still functionality that we have not ported over yet, the Graph API is the center of Facebook Platform moving forward and where all new features will be found."

and tried to simulate it on
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.addLike
and found same error.

I tried installed application on phones, and found Like feature was not working if they using REST API.
And if Like/UnLike feature has been deprecated, then what about the applications running on these devices using REST API.

Using graph API, how to do LIKE/UnLike a post, as in GRAPh API, we get a link
http://www.facebook.com/100001393844687/posts/109566102445124
which has to open on broswer/broswer Class which i don't want to use.

Please help in this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, call the `/postid/likes` connection with the `DELETE` http method.